# how to add more values to variable string

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this variable below,

```
var arr = { 
            lines: 1,
            angle: 2
          };
```

how would i append / push this into my `arr` variable?

```
var arr2 = { hi : 3 }
```

I've tried `push()` and just simply adding the two. but failed

```
var r = arr+''+arr2;
alert(r.toSource());
```

the `alert` gives me this

```
(new String("[object Object][object Object]"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a new property in a static way, like this:

```
arr.hi = 3;
```

but if you want to add all the properties from another object (a merge of object's properties) here a simple snippet:

```js
var arr = { 
  lines: 1,
  angle: 2
};

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

var arr2 = {
    hi : 3,
    jsIs: "aWeSoMe"
};

//add all the key/value pairs of arr2 to arr
Object.keys(arr2).forEach(function (key) {
    arr[key] = arr2[key]; 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign that into arr variable using

```
// if you want to enter object itself
arr.arr2 = arr2;
// if you want to remove arr2
delete arr2

// if you want to include just hi
arr.hi = arr2.hi;
// if you want to remove hi from arr2
delete arr2.hi
```